# #Aureliajs: Two routes have the same module. How to configure them?

Tags: routes, aurelia

Two routes have the same module. How to configure them? AuthorizeStep in place ( different authorization rules).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual route config is available in AuthorizeStep via `navigationInstruction.config`, so you could implement your logic using `route.name`, a remote request, or [additional route data](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/4), etc...

Demo: https://gist.run/?id=c8bdb291aa052ee92b4a1403e4ac10d1

We have 2 routes: `route1` and `route2`. While `route1` is accessible,  `route2` goes to an error page.

```
class AuthorizeStep {

  run(navigationInstruction, next) {

    if (navigationInstruction.config.name !== "unauthorized") {       
      var hasPermission = navigationInstruction.config.name === "route1";

      if (!hasPermission) {
        return next.cancel(new Redirect('unauthorized'));
      }
    }

    return next();
  }

}
```

ModuleId doesn't matter in this case. However, reusing the same VM could cause another issue. I'd consider changing viewmodel's current `activationStrategy` to `activationStrategy.replace` in order to get a new VM instance every time. [Docs: Reusing an existing VM section](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/7).